# swfobject onclick bind event to flash

Tags: flash, swfobject

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

How to bind onclick event to flash via swfobject?

For example i need to add onclick url, because there isn't built in url on click.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="clickpopup1" class="video1" href="#">Popup Link 1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#clickpopup1').click();
}



</script>
```

pulled it from a working file, in jquery format, hope this helps